# Permission Issue with created actions and VBO

Tags: views, actions

I’ve created a new action in a custom module using hook_action_info()

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */
function recruiteractions_action_info() {
  return array(
    'applicationentity_recruiterfillposition' => array(
      'type' => 'application', // <-- New entity type here
      'label' => t('Application Postion Fill Action'),
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'), //<-- Triggers an entity save.
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('any'),
    ),
  );
}
function applicationentity_recruiterfillposition(&$entity, $context = array()) {
  $app_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('application', $entity);

 $app_wrapper->field_job_status->set(‘1');
 $app_wrapper->save();

}
```

After enabling in VBO this all works fine and as it should.  The issue being when i set this to the role I need it to be set on.

the ‘Actions permissions (VBO) module is activated. and I can see the action; and have ticked the roles needed but with no joy.

I’ve also checked the ‘field_job_status’ permissions for the role I wish to allow to make changes.

On Drupal hook_action_info page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7  there is a post regarding 'behavior's impact on permissions and specifically mentions VBO.  however I'm not sure on what I need to do.  Has anyone got any examples for this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here was to set the permission I want in the access_callback of the custom entity itself.

so in my case the hook_entity_info

```
'access callback' => 'myentity_access_callback',
```

then added this in a function

```
function myentity_access_callback($roles = array()) {  // $op, $application = NULL, $account = NULL
 global $user;
 $roles = array(
   'administrator', 'anotheradminrole', 
 );
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```